# How do I lock a user's password?

Tags: macos, passwords, user-accounts, osx-mountain-lion

Most Linux distros I've used have a `passwd` program which can be used to do things like forcibly expire passwords, or lock them to temporarily prevent password-based login. OS X does have a `passed` program, but from its manual page, it doesn't seem to have any of these features. The `Users & Groups` preference pane doesn't seem to offer anything either save for a `Reset Password…` button, which is really not what I'm looking for.

How do I temporarily disable a user's password in OS X in such a way that I can reenable it without actually changing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pwpolicy`. I don't think all of its options are available with local accounts, but you can certainly disable accounts with it:

```
sudo pwpolicy -u someusername -setpolicy isDisabled=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it applies to some unspecified version of OS X, so you might want to be careful (try it with a dummy user account):

#### For OS X 10.5 or older

[Source article from hints.macworld](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20020310230730535)

> We can use the command line or NetInfo Manager to accomplish this. I
>   will show the commands via the Terminal command line because it is
>   easier for me. To disable the account, we insert the *:

```
sudo niutil -insertval . /users/user-in-question passwd '*' 0
```

> And to re-enable it, we remove the *:

```
sudo niutil -destroyval . /users/user-in-question passwd '*'
```

#### For OS X versions newer than 10.5

See [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/q/61214/127863) and the related answers. It's basically an exact duplicate of this question but for "OS X Server", which is basically the same as OS X as far as CLI administration is concerned.

By "disable password", I assume you mean "prevent from logging in". If that is *not* the case, then please clarify what you actually mean by "disable password", as this is a vague or unclear idea.

Comment: I'm on Mountain Lion, which doesn't seem to have a `niutil` program at all.

Comment: Sorry. http://stackoverflow.com/a/856531/420156

Comment: Err, how is that related?

Comment: Oh, `niutil` was replaced by `dscl`. `dscl` doesn't seem to have `insertval` or `destroyval` commands, though.

Comment: If you have not tested it, why even suggest it, considering the command actually DOES not work.

Comment: He said `OS X`, and didn't state what version. It'd be like giving advice to click on the Start Menu to someone who says they're running "Windows" when they're actually running Windows 8. By not being specific, the burden is on the OP to clarify, not on me to magically divine what version he is using.

Comment: @Ramhound Okay, so I didn't test it, but given that `which niutil` returned a not-found error, I think it's safe to assume that `niutil $anything` would only get me `zsh: command not found: niutil`.

Comment: @allquixotic Apologies. I did actually add the `osx-mountain-lion` tag  to the question when I said in a comment that I was on Mountain Lion. By “disable password”, I meant the equivalent of Linux's `sudo passwd --lock`, which adds a leading `!` to the password field of the relevant line in `/etc/shadow`, thus rendering the password hash invalid in an easily-undoable manner. This prevents password-based logins for that account _in such a way that I can reenable [the password] without actually changing it_, as I asked. OS X doesn't have such a `passwd` option, however, so I posted here.